# Clean pom.xml from all not used dependencies

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, test-automation-framework, maven, pom

Maybe this question was already posted here. If yes, please attach the link, I couldn't find out the same.
I would like to clean my old and not used dependencies from `pom.xml`, can someone advice me how to do this in better way?
Thanks for your help !

---

Anyone? any ideas? I marked some dependencies and run test, this gave me the option to check if all cycles will run as needed, but still have a lot of dependencies at the POM.XML that I would like to delete.

Answer (score 1):

Delete .m2 folder which contains all the dependencies form your user-home.Then 
re-build your package using "mvn clean package" command.All your dependencies will be removed and when you run a maven project ,the required dependencies will get downloaded and again stored in your local repository(.m2).